# Anylogic simultanious number of flowchart parts

Tags: java, anylogic

I want to add a number of short flowcharts parts which aren't special in a row. The flowchart are in a separate agent named Seperateflowchart. Via Excel I want to read in the number of flowchart parts in a row. If I read in 10, the flowchart part in the image is added 10 times in a row between my source and sink in the main.

Well I basically don't have a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best embed one flow chart block into one new agent type and put Enter and Exit blocks around it. Then, instantiate 10 of them (or whatever the data says) and make the actual agents visit these flow chart agents one by one.

See the help on how to use Enter and Exit blocks